# Finding order of pole at $1/z_0$ of $f(1/z)$ given order of pole at $z_0$ of $f(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

The title basically says it but the question is this:

> Let ord$(f, z_0) = n$ (where $z_0 \neq 0$) and let $g(z) = f(1/z)$. Show ord$(g, 1/z_0) = n$.

Given my somewhat limited understanding of poles and Laurent series, I seem to be looking to prove that inverting $f$'s input will not "interfere" with the coefficients of its Laurent series to make it so the resulting Laurent series (that of $g$) has non-zero coefficients where $f$'s did not or vice versa. From the definition I think we have that the Laurent series of $g$ about $1/z_0$ is
\begin{equation*}
g(z) = f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k \left(\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z_0}\right)^k
\end{equation*}
where the $a_k$'s are derived from the coefficients of $f$'s Laurent series in some way. However I don't know how to show that an $a_k$ will be zero iff its corresponding coefficient is zero (I did investigate somewhat into the integral form of the $a_k$'s but it proved fruitless).

I also have some basic results about the orders of poles of sums, products and reciprocals of functions but they don't seem to be relevant. Any direction with regards the solution or sources that could provide more understanding of this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z_0$ is a pole of order $n$ if $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)^n f(z) $ is finite and not zero (this is really the definition: note if $f$ is not identically zero there is only one $n$ for which this occurs). So let's look at $(z-1/z_0)^n g(z)$:
$$ \lim_{z \to 1/z_0}\left( z - \frac{1}{z_0} \right)^n g(z) = \lim_{z \to 1/z_0}\left( z - \frac{1}{z_0} \right)^n f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \lim_{z \to 1/z_0} \left(-\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^n\left( \frac{1}{z}-z_0 \right)^n f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) $$
But $(-z/z_0)^n \to (-1)^n \neq 0$, so the limit is nonzero if and only if $\lim_{z \to 1/z_0} \left( \frac{1}{z}-z_0 \right)^n f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ is nonzero, i.e. $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $1/z=z_0$.

Comment: I had not seen that limit definition (or had done in a less obvious form) and it seems to be what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Having the right definition is important! What's the definition you've had?

Comment: The way it was defined to me was that if there was a negative integer n such that a_n (the n^th coefficient of the Laurent series for a function about a point) was non-zero, but a_k was zero, for all k < n, then that function had a pole of order n at that point. I am struggling to find where the definition you've used above comes from. Can you direct me to somewhere that explains how it comes about and/or proves it from other more basic results?

Comment: Conway's book *Functions of one complex variable* talks about singularities in Chapter V. The definition I have used is essentially Definition 1.6 of that chapter, along with the characterisation of a removable singularity in Theorem 1.2. Your version is then noted as a consequence in the formula 1.7.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect!